# WP8 Pivot inside Panorama

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, pivot, panorama-control

I want to place Pivot inside Panorama and disable horizontal flick gestures for Pivot.

- If I set IsLocked="True" for Pivot, when I make horizontal flick,
  Panorama item is not changing.
- If i set IsHitTestVisible="False" for
  Pivot, I cant tap anything inside Pivot.

How can make this:

- Pivot can "sense" Tap and vertical flick gestures
- Panorama can "sense" horisontal flick gestures

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended behavior for Windows phone platform. Putting a Pivot inside a Panorama doesn't make sense at all and goes against WP design guidelines. Cant you have the same functionality with Panorama control alone?

Use `PanoramaItems` as you use `PivotItems`, if you want vertical scrolling use a `ScrollView` instead. Doing like you mentioned might make your app not certifiable.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <phone:Panorama Title="my application">
        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item1">
            <Grid>
                <ScrollViewer Height="480">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button Content="Button" />
                        <Button Content="Button" />
                        <Button Content="Button" />
                        <Button Content="Button" />
                        <Button Content="Button" />
                        <Button Content="Button" />
                        <Button Content="Button" />
                        <Button Content="Button" />
                        <Button Content="Button" />                                                       
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>                
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item2">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item3">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

With the above `Panorama` Page you can have horizontal scrolling among `PanoramaItems` and Vertical Scrolling for the content of the `PanoramaItem`

Comment: Using locked Pivot I can change content with nice visual effect. I will switch pivot-items in code. Panorama-items using for navigation.